# How to add action bar to second activity but not to first one

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.0

I have two activities, First is simple Login page in which I disabled action bar as I don't need it there, second activity is the user feed section where I want to add action bar with text or search option and app drawer maybe. How do I add the action bar to second activity but not to first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make app theme like this to have no actionbars by default.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

In your AndroidManifest.xml file, in `<application>` tag add this line:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

And if you need action bar on some activity just add this to your activity layout file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="owo.owocar.driver.rides_history_entity.ui.HistorySingleActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_history_single" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a different theme for the 2nd activity.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    ...
</style>

<style name="LoginTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a NoActionBar style for the Apptheme:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Then in the layout of the activity where you want an action bar, you can include it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.xxx.xxx.Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/fragment" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This produces the bar on the top of your activity, without any buttons/text/menu. Create a toolbar inside your Activity.java:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply now use a [`Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar)

```
<android.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:title="Hello World"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    />
```

Then set it as an action bar in your `Activity.java` file

```
Toolbar myToolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     myToolbar = findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
     setActionBar(myToolbar);
}
```

Note that the `Toolbar` that is being used in the example above is `android.widget.Toolbar` and not `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar`